# Odd Checksum Result(s) - Not Receiving Expected Results

Tags: lua, checksum

I have been trying to produce a checksum based on a file header and am receiving conflicting results.  In the slave devices manual, it states the following to produce the checksum:

"A simple eight-bit calculation is used for the header checksum. The steps required are as follows:

1. Calculate the sum of the header bytes in a single byte. Alternatively calculate
   the sum and then AND the result with FFhex.
2. The checksum = FFhex - the sum from step 1."

Here, I have created the following code in Lua:

```
function header_checksum(string)
    local sum = 0
    for i = 1, #string do
       sum = sum + string.byte(i)
    end
    local chksum = 255 - (sum & 255)
    return chksum
end
```

If I send the following (4x byte) string down `print(header_checksum("0181B81800"))` I get the following result:

- 241 (string sent as you see it)
- 0 (each byte is changed to hex and then sent to function)

In the example given, it states that the byte should be `AD`, which is 173(dec) or \255.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with what I am doing; either the code written, my approach, or both?

Comment: Use `string:byte(i)` instead of `string.byte(i)`

Comment: A style nit here is that you named the parameter `string` which is also the name of a standard module, specifically the module which is the metatable for all strings and generally found in `_G.string`. Overloading the name is perfectly legal Lua, but it is a source of confusion for the human reader who will be used to seeing `string.byte()` used to refer directly to the function.

Comment: @RBerteig good point.  I'm too easily confused, especially when it comes to the bit32 library and how to appropriately use it.  I should stop making matters worse for me.  Your point is noted for future coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function header_checksum(header)
   local sum = -1
   for i = 1, #header do
      sum = sum - header:byte(i)
   end
   return sum % 256
end

print(header_checksum(string.char(0x01,0x81,0xB8,0x18,0x00))) --> 173
```